# Как вывести значения из словаря в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, print, dict

У меня есть словарь:

```py
person = {
  'name' : {
    'last_name': 'Иванов', 
    'first_name': 'Иван', 
    'middle_name': 'Иванович'
  }, 
  'address': [
    'г. Андрюшки', 
    'ул. Васильковская д. 23б', 
    'кв.12'
  ], 
  'phone': {
    'home_phone': '34-67-12', 
    'mobile_phone': '8-564-345-23-65', 
    'mobile_phone_2': 'Нет'
  }
}
```

Как вывести `last_name` и `first_name` в одну строку? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `print(person['name']['last_name'], person['name']['first_name'])`

Answer (score 3):

```py
print(f"{person['name']['last_name']} {person['name']['first_name']}")
```

Comment: На всякий случай (если автору это важно): [f-строки](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings) доступны в версиях python 3.6 +

Answer (score 1):

```
print(person['name']['last_name'],person['name']['first_name'])
```